# Auto login to RDP then log out of PC

Tags: wsh

I need to create a script to launch a RDP file when the user logs into windows, ideally as shell so they dont have local access to their desktop. When the log out the RDP server it then logs them out of the windows machine.

I have a test Win 7 VM and this works perfectly:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run "mstsc.exe /multimon \\ashdom01\NETLOGON\RDS\Desktop.rdp", 1, TRUE
shell.Run "logoff"
```

When i try this on the win 7 Physical machine when i login it logs me out of windows straight away back to press CTRL ALT Del to login. I dont know whats wrong.

If this cannot work is there a way to create a batch file to launch the RDP file then loop through checking task manager for mstsc.exe then when it sees it end it logs the user out of windows.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards
Allister